# Coletar Data e Hora em um Formulario Reativo

Tags: angular

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário reativo no Angular 5 e gostaria de armazenar a Data/Hora em um DateTime. No caso, o usuário deveria de alguma forma informar a data e hora de um evento em específico. Todavia, não encontrei uma forma de armazenar no formControlName esse dado direto na view. Alguém já passou por isso? Qual foi a solução adotada?

Eu estou fazendo algo que parece uma gambiarra. Eu criei o dateTime no formBuilder e coloquei como input hidden na view. Aí eu coloquei um timepicker e um datepicker, junto os dois no componente e passo através de ngModel para o dateTime. Parece meio que gambiarra, então gostaria de encontrar outras formas para resolver isso.

No HTML, eu fiz desta forma:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
      <input materialize="pickadate" type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Selecione a Data" [materializeParams]=datePickerParams
        [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="atualizaData($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      <label> Data </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">
      <input materialize="pickatime" type="text" class="timepicker" placeholder="Selecione a Hora" [materializeParams]="[{twelvehour: false}]"
        [(ngModel)]="hora" (ngModelChange)="atualizaHora($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      <label> Hora  </label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" formControlName="dataHora" [(ngModel)]="dataHora">
```

Ou seja, coloquei dois input com ngModel, um responsável por pegar a data e o outro para pegar a hora. Aí estou colocando logo após um input hidden que recebe a dataHora, que eu trabalho lá no component.ts, concatenando com o Moment.js:

```
  atualizaData($event) {
    this.dataHora = moment($event + ' ' + this.hora, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
  }

  atualizaHora($event) {
    this.dataHora = moment(this.data + ' ' + $event, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
  }
```

Não sei se essa seria a melhor forma de resolver essa questão, o código acabou ficando um pouco sujo.

Comment: Seja mais claro em sua pergunta, coloque algum exemplo e o código fonte.

Comment: Acabei de colocar